# solve the inequality of $\frac{-3+e^x}{-e^x+1}> 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality

solve the inequality of

$$\frac{-3+e^x}{-e^x+1}> 0$$

one of my friend say that let $x  \neq 0$  we've $ -e^x+1 \neq 0$  then $-3+e^x> 0$

$$-3+e^x> 0  \implies  e^x> 3 \implies x>ln(3)$$

$S=(ln(3),+\infty)$

- how can i proof him that he is wrong

can i use the fact  :

$$\frac{a}{b} > 0 \iff a > 0 \textrm{ or } (b > 0 \textrm{ and } b \neq 0)  $$

Comment: Tell him to substitute any number in that range and see the result.

Comment: When $-e^x+1\ne 0$ it does not mean it is positive...

Comment: In this interval, only numerator is positive...But the denominator must be considered too

Comment: Your equivalence is false. Saying $\dfrac ab>0$ just means $a$ and $b$ have the same sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever there is an additional term in the denominator, it is a good idea to multiply both sides of the inequality by the square of the denominator, as it keeps the direction of the inequality. So we have
$$(e^x-3)(1-e^x)>0$$
Now, for the inequality to be satisfied we want either (i) $e^x-3>0$ *and*  $1-e^x>0$ or (ii) $e^x-3<0$ *and* $1-e^x<0$.

For condition (i), we need to have $e^x>3$ and $e^x<1$, i.e. $x>\ln 3$ and $x<0$, which is impossible to satisfy (so your friend is wrong).

For condition (ii), however, we require $e^x<3$ and $e^x>1$ which corresponds to a feasible solution $1<e^x<3$, or $0<x<\ln 3$

Comment: Note that conditions (i) and (ii) also follow directly from the original "fraction" form of the inequality; a fraction is positive if and only if the top and bottom are either both positive or both negative.

Answer (score 1):

we can solve $$\frac{-3 + e^x}{-e^x + 1} > 0 $$ by making a change of variable $u = e^x.$ now it reads as $$\frac{-3+u}{1-u}>0 $$ has critical numbers $1$ and $3$. by taking test points in each of the three regions separated by the critical points, we find that $$\frac{-3+u}{1-u}>0 \text{ for } 1 < u < 3.$$ this now translates to 
$$\frac{-3 + e^x}{-e^x + 1} > 0 \text { for } 0 < x < \ln 3.$$

Answer (score 1):

Quote: "...let $x \neq 0$ we've $−e^x+1 \neq 0$ then $−3+e^x>0$."

Actually not quite! You're multiplying both sides by the denominator, but if that denominator is negative, then you have to *flip the inequality sign*.

So there are really two cases:

Case 1: Suppose $-e^x + 1 > 0$; that is, assume $x < 0$. Then your original proof shows you must get $x > \ln 3$...except that this contradicts the condition that $x < 0$, so these solutions are invalid. This case yields no solutions at all.

Case 2: Suppose $-e^x + 1 < 0$; that is, assume $x > 0$.  Then we get (multiplying both sides and *flipping* the inequality):
$$
-3 + e^x < 0
$$
That is, $e^x < 3$, so $x<\ln 3$.  Combining that with the condition $x>0$ for Case 2, we get the solutions $0 < x < \ln 3$.  There were no solutions from Case 1, so this is our final answer: $x$ must belong to the open interval $(0, \ln 3)$.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, lets dicover the zeros of the numerator and denominator:

$$-3+e^x = 0 \Leftrightarrow e^x=3\Leftrightarrow x=\ln3.$$

$$-e^x+1=0\Leftrightarrow e^x=1\Leftrightarrow x = 0.$$

Then make a table where you can study the sinal of the functions :

[image]

From the table, you can conclude that:

$$\frac{-3+e^x}{-e^x+1}> 0\Leftrightarrow x\in ]0,\ln3[.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your fact is not true. It must be as 
$${a\over b}\gt 0\iff \big(a\gt 0 \quad\text{and}\quad b\gt 0\big )\quad or\quad \big(a\lt 0 \quad\text{and}\quad b\lt 0\big )$$

Comment: if we replace $\gt$ by $\geq$, $\leq$ or $\ $ ur fact still true

Comment: b is in denominator, so it can not be zero.